# div's won't position to the top of the container

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have blocks inside a container which can be dragged within their container. and can also be re-sized south. The default position is 7 div's side-by-side. all of them should be positioned at the top of the container, but instead,they appear one under another on the x-axis. I can't figure this out and would appreciate very much any help. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bq4B/) to demonstrate the problem and the html/css below. Thank you.

```
#calCon {
          height:400px;
          width:700px;
          border:1px solid grey;
          margin:0px;
        }

.date   {
          width:98px;
          height:30px;
          border:1px solid blue;
          background-color:green;
          position:relative;
          top:0px;
        }

<div id = "calCon">
   <div class = "date" style = "left:0;">cell 0</div>
   <div class = "date" style = "left:100px;">cell 1</div>
   <div class = "date" style = "left:200px;">cell 2</div>
   <div class = "date" style = "left:300px;">cell 3</div>
   <div class = "date" style = "left:400px;">cell 4</div>
   <div class = "date" style = "left:500px;">cell 5</div>
   <div class = "date" style = "left:600px;">cell 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with floating left is that when you re-size one cell the one to the left jumps underneath it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the inline styling for `.date` element and add `position: absolute;` to it. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/PLmE2/)

***Note:** When you absolute positioning an element inside container element you must use `margin-left` instead of `left` to contain absolute positioned element inside the parent element.

```
<div id ="calCon">
  <div class="date">cell 0</div>
  <div class="date">cell 1</div>
  <div class="date">cell 2</div>
  <div class="date">cell 3</div>
  <div class="date">cell 4</div>
  <div class="date">cell 5</div>
  <div class="date">cell 6</div>
</div>


.date {
  position: absolute;
  width: 98px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: green;
}
.date:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.date:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.date:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
.date:nth-of-type(4) {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
.date:nth-of-type(5) {
  margin-left: 400px;
}
.date:nth-of-type(6) {
  margin-left: 500px;
}
.date:nth-of-type(7) {
  margin-left: 600px;
}
```

Comment: great solution. Clearly you have a good understanding of the perils of resizable div's. This is the solution I will use. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

add `display: inline-block;` to your date class

not really sure what you're going for, but if you're not intending the giant white spacing between your `class` elements, then just remove the inline style tags that set their left position and you can simply do a `float:left;` in your css

http://jsfiddle.net/4Bq4B/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to position your elements absolute within the container.

This means setting `position: relative` on your container. and `position: absolute` on your child elements. This basically means your child elements will be absolutely positioned relative to to the container they are in.

Here is a working codepen: http://codepen.io/JTLR/pen/ojgLy

Another method is to put `float: left` or `display: inline-block` on the child elements, which will make them sit next to eachother. Bare in mind that inline-block elements have spacing between them by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand position: relative means. Here make **position:absolute** in the date class.It will slove your problem.